# sencha android packaging error - undocumented parameter?

Tags: extjs

My sencha config seems to be missing a parameter, can't figure out where it's being generated from the build.

Executing `sencha package build config.json`

With the config as specified in the sencha docs the tool generates the command:

`android create project --target android-7 --name appname --activity STActivity --path apppath --package pkg`

which generates the errors

> Failed to create android project Failed to package application [ERROR]
>   Error: Target id is not valid. Use 'android list targets' to get the
>   target ids.

There have been [similar complaints](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?190729-andriod-application-build-native&p=800012) on the sencha forums. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use Android SDK manager to install the level 7 platform. Unless you need something from a higher level in your application it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If this not working you can try other alternative:
  create android project using cordova command line interface

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

and Then package your sencha application using

```
sencha app build package
```

and paste this content into asset/www folder andorid cordova app .